# Setting python3.2 as default instead of python2.7 on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos

Currently running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 , and it has python2.7 as default. In the terminal, i type 'python' and it automatically pulls up python2.7. I don't want that.

from terminal I have to instead type 'python3.2' if i want to use python3.2.

How do i change that?

Comment: As a note, ``python3`` should also work fine, which is a little easier to type, if not a solution. You might run into issues on OS X with the presumption being ``python`` will be linked to ``python2`` - generally [where that link is pointed is down to the distribution](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), and kept consistent internally, so changing it might cause breakage.

Comment: shouldn't this be on superuser?

Comment: Don't think so as it's more related to python than terminal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The safest way is to set an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
 alias python=python3
```

That way you avoid breaking things for scripts relaying on `python` being python2.

Comment: thank you! Also, alias python=python3 didnt work but alias python = python3.2 did work.

Answer (score 4):

You could edit the default python path and point it to python3.2

Open up `~/.bash_profile` in an editor and edit it so it looks like

`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH`

Comment: I think that the first option is much simpler and more effective.

Answer (score 3):

If you have python 2 and 3 on brew. Following worked for me.

`brew unlink python@2`

`brew link python@3`  (if not yet linked)