# How can I specify rmarkdown to use Python3 instead of Python 2?

Tags: r, r-markdown, python-3.5

I am trying to run python as rmarkdwon code chunks. I was successful but rmarkdown by default uses Python2 and I want it to use Python 3. I am running it on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.6 installed and I installed anaconda with Python 3.5, which is the one I want rmarkdown use.

Here is the code and output of the python chunk in rmarkdown

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

and the output:

```
2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336852/setting-python3-2-as-default-instead-of-python2-7-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `engine.path = '/path/to/python3'` to override the python (2) executable. For example,

````
---
title: "python"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{python}
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

```{python, engine.path = '/usr/bin/python3'}
import sys
print(sys.version)
```
````

---

[image]

Comment: I have installed python 3.5 in the directory:     'code' /<root>/home/user1/anaconda3/bin 'code', so I just used 'code' ```{python, engine.path = '~/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3'} 'code' and I get the following error: 'code'Error in system2(cmd, code, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) : 
  error in running command
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted 'code'

Comment: Open up a bash terminal and type in `which python3`. Whatever that returns is what you should use for `engine.path`.

Comment: What is the **exact** path returned by `which python3`?

Comment: which pyhton3 returned /home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3 so I use this ```{python, engine.path = '~/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3'}. Still have the same error. Also tried ```{python, engine.path = '~/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3'} whit no success.

Comment: Try using *exactly* this path: `/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3`. Currently you are entering `~/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3`, which is presumably expanding to `/home/user1/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Answer (score 5):

You can select your desired python version, as default, with an R chunk:

````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(engine.path = '/usr/bin/python3')
```
````

From now on your python chunks will use Python3:

````
```{python}
import sys
print(sys.version)
```
````

This way to select python version avoids to add the `engine.path` variable to every code chunk.

Comment: Neither setting my `opts_chunk` like this nor editing my .Rprofile to add `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("<path_to_python3>", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))` has set the default python correctly. I have no trouble setting an individual chunk to run python3 by setting the `engine.path` for that chunk, but setting all chunks to default to python3 hasn't worked; it still defaults to python2. I'm on version 1.1.423 of RStudio for Mac and R version 3.3.3. Would love to hear any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are running Python 3.x, which I am, I had to do the following (obviously your path to the Python3 executable might be different):

````
```{r Setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set('python', engine.path='/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3')

```
````

And could then create a chunk using just `python` and it would run in the correct version:

````
```{python, cache=TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE}

import sys
print(sys.version)

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reticulate package and insert an R chunk at the beginning:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")
```
````